# How to extract strings from .m file for localization

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring

I want to extract text string from source code in IOS automatically.

I found some solutions in googling

```
find . -name *.m | xargs genstrings -o ./LocalizationTest/en.lproj/
```

this only extract string if I use NSLocalizedStringFromTable like following

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Not Reachable", @"AFNetworking", nil);
```

I just make text like NSString* test = @"test string". So all of my text did not extracted from that command.

And Following command just extract string in XIB file

```
find . -name *.xib | xargs -t -I '{}' ibtool --generate-strings-file '{}'.strings '{}'
```

I want to extract all string from .m file automatically.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why haven't you used `NSLocalizedString` if you want to do localisation?

Comment: I'm going to use NSLocalizedString or NSLocalizedStringFromTable eventually. I want to extract list of string, choose some strings and replace that NSLocalizedString. So I need to generate a list of string automatically.

Comment: You really need to switch to using `NSLocalizedString` first, then extracting the strings will be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ibtool` considers only strings wrapped in the `NSLocalizedString` macro because the localization functionality requires this macro anyway.